# indicate whether value is infinite, indicate whether it is +infinite or - infinite

Tags: calculus

if the limiting value is infinite , indicate weather its positive infinity or negative infinite

1. $f(x)=x^3 - 4x^2-4$
2. $f(x) = \frac{x^2 - 2x +3}{2x^2 +5x +1}$
3. $f(x) = \frac{2x+1}{ 3x^2 + 2x -7}$
4. $f(x)= \frac{3x^2-6x+2}{2x-9} $

==========================
Here's my explanation of the ans.

1. its quite simple first lets note the $x^3$ term as $x$ approaches negative infinity $y$ will also approach negative infinity, $x^2$ approaches negative infinity $y$ approached infinity but because the its $-4x^2$ we have $x^3<4x^2$ as $x$ approaches negative infinty thus the whole function as $x$ approaches negative infinity is approaching negative infinity (-4 term is constant and generally wont be considered and doesnt need to be considered here) 
   as x approaches infinity we note that $x^3$ approaches infinity and so does $4x^2$ but $x^3$ approaches it much faster than $x^2$ does thus since$ x^2<x^2$ we can conclude that the function approaches infinity we could prove this mathematically using a epsilon delta group but i suggest that you are in entry level cal so this analysis of the functions behavious will be sufficient. (Is this correct please help me()
2. we have a rational function which means we can use a trick to define the behavior as x approaches infinity simply devide the top and the bottom by the highest power of x and we find that (x^2/x^2-2x/x^2+3/x^2)/(2x^2/x^2+5x/x^2+... 
   we notice that all the terms that do not have a x^2 will approach zero because $x^2>2x $ for example so these terms simply disapear. the terms that we can calcerl $x^2$ we take the coefficient of these terms and can conclude that the limit as x approaches infinity will equal $1/2$. 
   as x approach negative infinity we need to consider the function in the for on $f(x)/g(x)$ where $f(x)$ is our numerator and $g(x)$ is the denominator and lets look at the behavior of these functions as they approach negative infinity. note that f(x) x^2 will become a positive value such that $x^2>-2x$ so the top $f(x)$ will approach infinity. the bottom part g(x) we get $3x^2$ approaches infinity and not that approaches negative infinity but we not that $2x^2$ approaches its terminal point much faster that $5x$ does and also $2x^2>5x$ so we can conclude that $g(x)$ also approaches infinity and thus the function approaching negative infinity will approach infinity. 
   (is this correct?)
   I

Comment: Can you please rewrite your equations into Mathjax? They arent written clearly at the moment. For example, is "3/2x^2" meant to be $\frac{3}{2x^2}$ or $\frac32 x^2$? http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: As @5xum mentioned, using Mathjax would be great as it would remove some of the confusion in the fractions. I looked at the answers and figured out what you probably meant, so I edited the question where I could. Just waiting on it to be reviewed.

Comment: @LonelyMathematician I think you are right, I approved your edits. However, Let us just wait for the OP to confirm if the edits are correct.

Comment: @5xum sounds like a great idea :)

Comment: exactly right, that's what i want to be the equation of mine. Thanks

Comment: Also, @Camille Valerio, if you could clarify what the limits are, that would help too. This is important; the first function approaches infinity as $x$ goes to infinity. But as $x\rightarrow-\infty$, then $f(x) \rightarrow -\infty$. So please clarify. **Edit**: I realize now we're doing both $\infty$ and $-\infty$. But pointing that out in the question would be appreciated :)

Comment: I have to make factoring right?